# Unable to install Psycopg2 in Docker alpine image

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run docker for an alpine image but unable to install psycopg2 from requirements.txt, tried all the solutions for similar problems but none worked.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-miniconda3:python3.7 as base

FROM base as builder
# RUN apt-get update \
#     && apt-get install -y build-essential \
#     && apt-get install -y nginx 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
# Make sure we use the virtualenv:
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
RUN pip install gunicorn


RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


FROM base
RUN apk add nginx bash
# RUN conda install python==3.7.1
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /opt/venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY . /usr/src/app/rapid-nrn-backend
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/rapid-nrn-backend

CMD ["/bin/bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8000
```

**requirements.txt**
[requirements.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XTOG9PxnzfwqI5sCb6UE5RdlLor590hn)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're already installing `psycopg2-binary` you don't need to install `psycopg2`. Remove psycopg2 from your requirements.txt

Comment: Removed but no effect .. Error: pg_config executable not found.